# Can you put multiple context menu items into its own group to remove clutter?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu

I have searched a lot and the same answers keep coming up.

- Edit the registry / download one of a few context menu changing tools.
- Disable or remove the item you no longer want to see, or
- Add new menu items if this is what you wish to do

Not one article, blog post, comment or image showed me what I am trying to achieve. I am starting to believe that the context menu configuration in the registry is way too complex to even allow this.

When I right-click on a file, I would like it to show me the bare necessities and be able to hover over "Other", or whatever I call the folder, and see my custom installed items.

I am running Windows 10 in case there are caveats between the other versions.

So all I want to know is if this is possible and if so, if you know how, please do let me know too.

---

**Edit:**

The image below is sort of an example of what I am talking about. The menu on the left has items from different applications randomly placed which bugs me. It's bloated, confusing and hard to find what I am looking for.

What I want to do is put them in a sub folder and obviously remove the ones I don't use. Creating that sub folder and moving the items on that menu is where I am stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same thing, There isn't really a way to clear out the clutter based on my research but you can use the registry to automatically clear the clutter. It's not really that great, but it does do a bit of clearing.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FlightedFeatures

New > DWORD > ImmersiveContextMenu Value data 0 to disable or delete ImmersiveContextMenu.
```

The effect is visble after restarting the explorer. To disable run this code as a batch file.

```
@echo off powershell -windowstyle hidden -command "Start-Process cmd
-ArgumentList '/s,/c,REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FlightedFeatures" /V ImmersiveContextMenu /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F' -Verb runAs"

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe start explorer.exe
```

Grabbed from [Here](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_disable_or_enable_wide_context_menus_in_windows_10.html)